# Gatsby - How to query for all YAML in a subfolder of src/data/ using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, yaml, gatsby

I'm trying to query for all YAML files in a subfolder of my data folder. I'm using `gatsby-transformer-yaml` to parse the YAML data. My filetree looks something like this:

```
content/
    posts/
        book1.md
        book2.md
src/
    data/
        books/
            quotes1.yaml
            quotes2.yaml 
    templates/
        booknote.tsx
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-yaml/?=yaml#single-object), I should be able to make a query called `allBooksYaml` which would return all of the quotes in `quote1.yaml` and `quote2.yaml`. However, when I look at the GraphiQL playground, the only queries I can make are `allQuote1Yaml` and `allQuote2Yaml`. (1) Is this a bug? Or is something wrong with my setup?

The reason why I want to do this is so that I can filter the result of `allBooksYaml` with the title of the book and display the correct quotes for each page generated with the `booknote.tsx` template. If I don't do this, I think I would have to make an individual page/GraphQL query  manually for each book note post I want to create. (2) Is there a better way to link data in a YAML file and the Markdown/Page component?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [plugin's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-yaml/), given:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   plugins: [
>     `gatsby-transformer-yaml`,
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>       options: {
>         path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
>       },
>     },
>   ],
> }
> ```
>
> Where the source folder `${__dirname}/src/data/` contains the `.yaml` files.

Having in mind also, that you can structure your folder to generate an array or a single object:

> - Array of Objects: Where each file represents a collection. (you probably want this one)
> - Single Object: Where each subfolder represents a collection; each file represents one “record”.

So, if your path is `./src/data/books` you should be able to query for all books, but this will generate a specific node for all books (single object).

For the second question, I think the best optimal solution is to generate dynamically the pages using `gatsby-node.js`, querying all markdown books and there, send the title (or another unique field) to the template via context and filter there for each specific book, so your quotes will need to contain a field with an identifier that will match the book, mostly what you said but without the manual approach. Which, at the same time, is more or less a blog approach.

Further reference: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do just that by using the following config:

```
"gatsby-transformer-yaml",
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
  },
},
"gatsby-transformer-yaml",
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
  options: {
  path: `${__dirname}/content`,
  },
},
```